# custom validator for jQuery Validation Engine

Tags: jquery

The *Name* field in a form has a default value of "Name" (obviously). I'm trying to create a custom validator in case the user does not replace "Name" with own name.

I've put the following in the jquery.validationEngine-custom.js file.

```
"notDefaultName":{ 
    "regex":/^(Name.+|(?!Name).*)$/,
    "alertText": "* Please enter your name"
},
```

, but it doesn't trigger when user submits with default value.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Can you specify the triggered function as soon as the submit is clicked

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question :/